# iPhone X Simulator Screenshot Without Notch

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Does anyone know how to take screenshots without the notch on the iPhone X simulator?

When I try and upload the screenshots with the notch on iTunes connect, I get an error saying "images can't contain transparencies". Command + S on the simulator creates screenshots with the notch but iTunes connect will not accept them.

Comment: What makes you think that has anything to do with the notch?

Comment: I have successfully uploaded screenshots from the iPhone X simulator

Comment: @matt I think the notch is the issue because there is a transparency where the notch is and the message says it can't contain transparencies.  I double checked and the resolution is correct.  I did just realize I was on xCode 9.0 which doesn't support iOS 11.1.  So I'm downloading xCode 9.1 which may fix the issue.

Comment: Well, according to Apple, "iPhone X screenshots are optional". So I say ignore the whole issue. However, if they have a problem with transparency, I would suggest you check whether the screen shot has an alpha channel and, if it does, remove it.

Answer (score 14):

A bit late, but might be still relevant to people.

If you hold **option** (⌥) key right before tapping on `File/New Screenshot` (or simply hold ⌘ + s + ⌥) you'll be able to take a screenshot without the device mask.

[image]

Comment: Yes! Big help, I’ve been looking for this option for an hour in the new Xcode... In Xcode 9.0 (I think that’s what I had previously?) the default screenshot was without the device mask

Comment: can I make instant screenshot without make and without this dialog? it takes time and keyboard/mouse interactions to continue

Answer (score 3):

As other commenters are saying, this seems to be just a problem of your screenshot containing a transparency, or alpha channel. To get rid of it, open the screenshot in Preview on your Mac, go to `File -> Export...` and save it as a PNG. Make sure that the Alpha checkbox is unchecked.